# How to override "Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels" on media upload page - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, media

My client needs to upload high-res images for her online press kit.

She is getting this error: "Post-processing of the image failed likely because the server is busy or does not have enough resources. Uploading a smaller image may help. Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels."

The images she wants to upload are about 2.5MB in size, and are 4272 x 2848 with 72dpi.

If I crop the images, to be 2500x1667 at 72dpi, they upload fine (meeting the 2500 pixel suggested max size.)

Is there a way to allow the larger pixel images as indicated above (4272 x 2848)?

I am not sure which php setting is the issue - I think it might be memory size, but if it is, I am not sure where to change it or what amount to set it to, to allow twice the pixel max size allowance (going from 2500 to say 5000 pixels)... or if that is even allowed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my system details:

- WordPress Version: 5.5.1
- MySQL Version: 5.6.41
- BootStrap Version: 3.3.1
- PHP version   7.3.22 (Supports 64bit values)
- PHP max input variables   1000
- PHP time limit    30
- PHP memory limit  256M
- Max input time    60
- Upload max filesize   256M
- PHP post max size 260M

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `big_image_size_threshold` filter to change or disable this behavior.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/big_image_size_threshold/

> If the original image width or height is above the threshold, it will be scaled down. The threshold is used as max width and max height. The scaled down image will be used as the largest available size, including the _wp_attached_file post meta value.
>
> Returning false from the filter callback will disable the scaling.

Comment: Thanks @04FS, that did the trick for me.  However, just to note, before I implemented this change, when I tried to upload the larger files, they actually did upload, but they were displayed in the media library as a blank image icon.  If you clicked on it, you did get the attachment detail page, but you couldn't insert the image into any page.  But if you wanted to link to the image, you could use the file URL provided on the detail page.  So it was there in its full size, just not very usable!  The above explanation doesn't seem to fit what I was seeing.. the image wasn't scaled down.

Comment: For people searching on usage, here is how I entered it in my functions.php file:

    function td_big_image_size_threshold( $threshold, $imagesize, $file, $attachment_id ) {
    return 5000;
    }
    add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', 'td_big_image_size_threshold', 10, 4 );

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem. Disabling `big_image_size_threshold` didn't fix it. I think my issue is that after upgrading to PHP 7.4, the version of ImageMagick running on my host for PHP 7.4 is bad or something. I fixed the issue by using GD instead of ImageMagick. Just add this to `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter('wp_image_editors', function($editors) {
    return ['WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick'];
});
```

One thing to note: If you don't have GD installed, WP will default back to using Imagick. So there's little risk in making this change. Though if it doesn't resolve the problem, you might want to check that GD is actually installed.

Answer (score 1):

This verified answer didn't work for me

The apache2 errors should be always in your

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

So, you can identify the problem easily.

I fixed it by myself:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

See this post there are many solutions for this: [Link](https://www.techify.club/2020/11/fix-post-processing-of-the-image-failed-wordpress-error-all-solutions/)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue and struggled with it for nearly a whole day - trying answers from this page and from this WordPress topic also: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-processing-of-the-image-failed-error/

Eventually, what resolved the problem for me was that I went to the WordPress Updates page and simply Re-installed WordPress - everything has been perfectly fine since.

I am running a network on WP version 5.7 with php 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Main case : if you using any plugin in WordPress For image compress then its happens
in my case i was using WP Compress in WordPress i get most of this error when uploading image , after all i deactivate this plugin & problem fixed .

Answer (score 0):

I have this with shortpixel plugin, so definitely check for plugins that interfere with images.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34943978)