# Can't fix “Suggested maximum image size is 2560 pixels” error in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

While trying to upload some large image I get:

[image]

Tried to add the following to `www/wp-content/themes/<my theme>/functions.php`:

```
// completely disable image size threshold
add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );

//switch to GD
add_filter('wp_image_editors', function($editors) {
    return ['WP_Image_Editor_GD', 'WP_Image_Editor_Imagick'];
});
```

, but without a success.

GD module is enabled:

[image]

PHP version: 7.4

WordPress version: 6

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question here:
[How to override "Suggested maximum size is 2500 pixels" on media upload page - wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157086/how-to-override-suggested-maximum-size-is-2500-pixels-on-media-upload-page-w)

And this is the link that helped a guy, he explains how he used it in the comment of an answer:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/big_image_size_threshold/

> For people searching on usage, here is how I entered it in my
> functions.php file: function td_big_image_size_threshold( $threshold,
> $imagesize, $file, $attachment_id ) { return 5000; } add_filter(
> 'big_image_size_threshold', 'td_big_image_size_threshold', 10, 4 );

If that's not the case, you can go to the updates page and reinstall Wordpress.